# Laravel 5 - I can't retrieve file uploaded even if they are actually uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-upload, storage

I'm trying to create a simple files uploader and actually files are uploaded, I can also delete them but actually I cannot access them.
I give you an example: If i want to upload an image everything seems to go fine ([I can also return the Url after upload happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvmZ7.jpg)) as you can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AovNT.jpg). 
But when I try to go that url I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agdur.jpg) or if I try to insert the URL as src for `<img>` the picture doesn't load.

Note that I've already run `php artisan storage:link` as you can see in the second picture. I'm using Homestead and Virtual box as dev enviroment.

Here's some code: 
**From my upload controller**

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('file_field');
    $ext = $file->guessClientExtension();

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        'file_field' => 'required',
        'comment' => 'required',
        'confidentiality' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    $file_model = File::create([
        'id_paziente' => Input::get('idPatient'),
        'id_audit_log' => Input::get('idLog'),
        'id_file_confidenzialita' => Input::get('confidentiality'),
        'file_nome' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
        'file_commento' => Input::get('comment'),
    ]);

    $file_model->save();
    return Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs("/patient/".Input::get('idPatient'), $file, $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'public');
}
```

**My config/filesystem.php**

```
<?php

return [

'default' => 'public',

'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],

];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation for File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-urls)

I have the same problem I use this method, to store my upload image url

```
Storage::url ($file);
```

And display it into blade on src for img

Comment: Hum, well for me it's work :/ good luck, sorry for not helping you more